# Using PREMIRRORS in Bitbake configuration

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

How do I use `PREMIRRORS` in Bitbake local configurations or recipes?

I want to provide my own download locations for some slow or inaccessible third-party URLs, but the [official `PREMIRRORS` documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PREMIRRORS) is vague and lacks examples.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note: These results are based on experimentation with Yocto 2.3, but probably apply to 2.5 as well.

### A simple example

Suppose that your recipe file contains this target URL:

```
SRC_URI = "http://download.example.com:8080/foo/bar/baz-1.0.tar.gz"
```

Then in your `local.conf`, you can define your custom download location as:

```
PREMIRRORS_prepend = "http://download\.example\.com:8080/.* http://my-mirror.example.com/copies/\n"
```

In this default case (with no special placeholders) Bitbake does *not* include the additional `/foo/bar` path elements, and instead tries to download just the filename from `http://my-mirror.example.com/copies/baz-1.0.tar.gz`

### Advanced examples

These samples use special predefined placeholders, which are detailed in the next section.

#### HTTP/HTTPS with same file structure

- Recipe: `SRC_URI = "https://example.com:1234/foo/bar.zip"`
- Setting: `PREMIRRORS_prepend = "http(s)?://example\.com(:\d+)?/.* http://mirror.local/PATH\n"`
- Attempts: `http://mirror.local/foo/bar.zip`

#### HTTP/HTTPS with flat structure

- Recipe: `SRC_URI = "https://example.com:1234/foo/bar.zip"`
- Setting: `PREMIRRORS_prepend = "http(s)?://example\.com(:\d+)?/.* http://mirror.local/MIRRORNAME\n"`
- Attempts: `http://mirror.local/example.com.1234.foo.bar.zip`

#### Just switch the hostname

- Recipe: `SRC_URI = "ftp://example.com:1234/foo/bar.zip"`
- Setting: `PREMIRRORS_prepend = "(\w+)://example\.com(:\d+)?/.* TYPE://mirror.local/PATH\n"`
- Attempts: `ftp://mirrors.local/foo/bar.zip`

### Placeholders in replacement URI

`PREMIRRORS` parses all matched URIs and provides five special placeholder values in the target URI. Supposing the matched URI is `http://host.example.com:1234/foo/bar/baz.txt`:

```
TYPE          https
HOST          host.example.com%3A1234
PATH          foo/bar/baz.txt
BASENAME      baz.txt
MIRRORNAME    host.example.com.1234.foo.bar.baz.txt
```

### Altering the `PREMIRRORS` variable

The `PREMIRRORS` variable consists of series of lines (separated by `\n`) each with a regular expression to match a URI, and then a replacement string, with both portions separated by a space.

Bitbake tries them in order of appearance, and you generally want your private mirrors to take priority, so prepend onto `PREMIRRORS`, ex:

```
PREMIRRORS_prepend = "http://original/location/.* http://alternate/location/\n"
```

### What file should I edit?

You can add entries to `PREMIRRORS` inside your bitbake recipes, but it is not recommended, since a major use of `PREMIRRORS` is for people reusing your recipe in some other context or location.

Instead, you can put it inside your [`local.conf`](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#structure-build-conf-local.conf) file in an existing build directory. Alternately, edit the source template which Poky script use when creating a new `local.conf` in a fresh build-directory.

### Other questions

#### What about `SOURCE_MIRROR_URL`?

The [`SOURCE_MIRROR_URL`](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.3/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SOURCE_MIRROR_URL) is a quick way to add a series of `PREMIRROR` entries for all supported protocols. For example, this setting:

```
INHERIT += "own-mirrors"    
SOURCE_MIRROR_URL = "TYPE://mirror.local/PATH"
```

is the same as writing:

```
PREMIRRORS_prepend = "\
cvs://.*/.*     TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \
svn://.*/.*     TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \
git://.*/.*     TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \
gitsm://.*/.*   TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \
hg://.*/.*      TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \ 
bzr://.*/.*     TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \
p4://.*/.*      TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \
osc://.*/.*     TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \ 
https?$://.*/.* TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \
ftp://.*/.*     TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \
npm://.*/?.*    TYPE://mirror.local/PATH \
"
```

It seems the `INHERIT`+`SOURCE_MIRROR_URL` directives will still work if used in your `local.conf` (as opposed to a particular recipe.) However, Bitbake will emit warnings, so it may not be the intended use-case. Ex:

```
WARNING: Invalid protocol in PREMIRRORS: ('cvs://.*/.*', 'TYPE://mirror.local/PATH')
```

#### How can I check and debug my settings?

The `-D` debug flag will cause `bitbake` to emit information about what URLs it attempts to download from. You can also use `-C do_fetch`, which will force it to try the fetch step and re-download anything needed for the given recipe.

```
bitbake -D -C do_fetch software-recipe-name-here
```

Here's some example debug output, showing the `PREMIRROR` URL it attempts to access:

```
DEBUG: some-software-1.0 do_fetch: Trying PREMIRRORS
DEBUG: some-software-1.0 do_fetch: Fetcher accessed the network with the command /usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 -nv --passive-ftp --no-check-certificate -P /home/user/build_foo/DL_DIR 'http://mirror.local/path/to/the/filename.ext
```

If you need to experiment and run `bitbake` many times, it will be faster to temporarily put your new `PREMIRRORS_prepend` directive into a particular test-recipe, as opposed to modifying the `local.conf`. This is because Bitbake won't need to re-parse all the other recipes whenever you change it.

#### What if I want to isolate a port-number, e.g. `http://host:123/foo`?

Apparently there's no easy way to get the `123` on its own. While `PREMIRRORS` allows you to *match* with regular expressions, it does not seem to support using captured text from the match inside the replacement URI.

The port number is present inside `HOST` and `MIRRORNAME`, but there's no standard mechanism to split those values apart.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up. What if I want to isolate a port-number, e.g. `http://host:123/foo`?

Maybe you can use captured.
Like:

```
org: "http://somewhere.org:1234/somedir1/somedir2/somefile_1.2.3.tar.gz"

reg: "http://somewhere.org(:\d+)?/.*"

sub: "http://somewhere2.org\\1/somedir3"
    
result: "http://somewhere2.org:1234/somedir3/somefile_1.2.3.tar.gz"
```

Comment: "Maybe you can"? Has this been tested? If so, with which version?