# Yocto build tips

Tags: yocto

When I build yocto, there are some files that has larges size and they take me a lot of time to dowload.
I tried placing them in sources/ but doing this is otiose. My question: Is there any way to pass checksum mechanism of yocto?

Thankyou so much for any helping!

Comment: Please ref to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940431/using-premirrors-in-bitbake-configuration

Answer (score 1):

The checksum in Yocto is used to make sure that downloaded files are not corrupted or tampered with.
Instead of trying to bypass the checksum mechanism, you can try using a download accelerator or mirror to download the files more quickly.

- You can also use a cache server to store the downloaded files, so you
  don't have to download them again in the future.
- If you need to re-download a file that was partially downloaded or
  corrupted, you can use the bitbake command with the -f flag to force
  a download.